# AWS Lambda function Timedout after 3 sec using AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am new to AWS and Go and I am trying to execute my Lambda function via AWS SAM CLI. But every time I try to do so I get the following error:

```
I0517 07:51:11.052078      13 main.go:62] Thumbnail Lambda successfully started 
I0517 07:51:13.696304      13 utils.go:99] Needed directories successfully created
2019-05-17 09:51:14 Function 'Thumbnail' timed out after 3 seconds
2019-05-17 09:51:14 Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers or statusCode in the response object). Response received:
```

I did not want to copy information I pass in the HTTP request since its sensitive.

Any idea how I can modify this 3 second timeout?

Comment: How did you set up your lambda? Via console? SDK? Cloudformation? For all of the above, you can set the value of the timeout. The default is 3 seconds, hence the above error. Edit: ah, you are using the SAM cli? You probably have a template.yaml file in your project. Search for 'Timeout' and check the value

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am using `template.yml` in order to set up my lambda. I forgot to re-build and re-run `sam local start-api` when I introduced `Timeout` property to it. Honest mistake, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 54):

The default timeout of Lambda functions is 3 seconds. You can set any value by updating the [Timeout](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction) property in your SAM template, e.g.

```
ExampleLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: .
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs10.x
    Timeout: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't pertain to `sam local start-api`, but if you're developing in PyCharm and running a single Lambda function with the PyCharm run button, there's another setting you might not have seen in the run configuration window where you can specify the timeout:

[image]