# AWS lambda timeout after 3 sec after importing dynamoose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dynamoose

In webstrom ide, using aws sam cli and lamdba functions, I added this line:
`const dynamoose = require('dynamoose')`
After that getting this error:
`Function 'HelloWorldFunction' timed out after 3 seconds. No response from invoke container for HelloWorldFunction`
Before that it was working perfectly fine. I have installed the dynamoose module as well.

Comment: Did you increased your functions timeout: `Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is three seconds. `?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda function Timedout after 3 sec using AWS SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182205/aws-lambda-function-timedout-after-3-sec-using-aws-sam)

Comment: Yes, I have increased timeout. Still no change.